# LCD & Li Ion batteries at -40°C

Tags: lcd, lithium-ion

Does anyone know of a product like a heating blanket or similar i can have customized to cover my electronic product to protect it against negative temperatures of -30 to -40 etc. 
My LCD and Li Ion batteries are not rated for -40 but I have an inquiry to sell into Russia and would like to know if anyone has used something that can help.
Rgds
Richard

Comment: What makes you think your product is going to be used at that sort of temperature?

Comment: We went to visit St Petersburg and during our visit it was -26°C but according to our agent there it gets colder

Comment: Our product is mounted in a stainless steel cabinet on the side of a truck

Comment: First off, don't make your cabinet out of steel, it will wick away any heat you put into it, read up on thermal design. Second of all, you need a resistor and run current through it, there are all types of resistors, wires, coils, pads, regular resistors. Run power through the resistor to create heat

Comment: You may already know this. Do not, under any circumstances, charge your lithium ion batteries when they are cold. Read the manufacturer's specifications and adhere to them.

Comment: @mkeith Understood!

Comment: @laptop2d Seems to be standard practice to use stainless cabinets but no one says i can't add insulation of some sort in the cabinet. We are currently doing tests with a resistive heating pad mounted inside the box which seems to work ok but will require changes to our design which i would like to avoid

Comment: Well, I mean there are two things you can do. Insulate and heat. Both can be done either to the equipment itself, or to the cabinet. As far as heat sources, can you take heat from the vehicle itself? Either the engine coolant (seems complicated) or the vehicle electric system? Basically you need to get insulation outside of your electric product, and a heat source inside of the insulation. It is not that complicated, conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

Put some power resistors under your electronics, with a thermostat which will shut them down once you reach a temperature of +5°C or so. Remember to tell your customers that your device can take up to several minutes to start up.

[image]

Note that this will only help if your LCD and batteries are rated at -40°C *storage temperature*, since you most probably won't be able to keep the heating powered continuously.

You might consider providing some thermal insulation as @laptop2d suggested, but keep in mind that you'll have the opposite issue in summer when it will be hot outside and you'll struggle with dissipating extra heat from your electronics sitting inside a thermally insulated box.